# Can I use the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of variations here?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I would like to conclude that $Ke^{f}=1$ on $\partial M$ from the following:

We have $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary $\partial M$, $f\in C^{\infty}(\overline{M})$, $K$ is a constant. For $\varphi\in C^{1}(\overline{M})$, we have:

$$\int_{\partial M}\varphi^{2}(Ke^{f}-1)d\sigma=0.$$

Then, since $\varphi$ is arbitrary in $C^{1}(\overline{M})$, I would like to use the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations to conclude that $Ke^{f}-1=0$ on $\partial M$. However, I am not sure if I can use such Lemma. Can I?

I also have that $Ke^{f}-1\geq0$ on $\partial M$, which has allowed me to conclude that $\varphi^{2}(Ke^{f}-1)=0$ almost everywhere on $\partial M$, but from this I believe, I cannot conclude that $(Ke^{f}-1)=0$ as I need. That is my guess, but I can be wrong.

Any help, would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you state the version of calculus lemma you would like to use? (which hypothesis) I don't get why it would fit here.

Comment: I am just looking at the multivariable functions version from Wikipedia, I honestly do not know if there is one for the case I am asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_the_calculus_of_variations

Comment: Technically, you cannot apply the fundamental lemma here, since it doesn't quite fit the standard hypotheses, but your intuition is broadly correct: the statement is true by a very similar argument. Can you think of a direct proof using bump functions?

Comment: If you have $Ke^f-1\geq 0$ then you’re done because the integrand is non-negative so vanishing of the integral implies the integrand vanishes a.e and hence by continuity, everywhere.